# 'routeProvider otherwise' is catching all the other links

Tags: angularjs

I have the following links:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="store">Stores</a></li>
        <li><a href="groups">Groups</a></li>
        <li><a href="purchases">Purchases</a></li>
        <li><a href="settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and this is the routeProvider config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
    .when('/store', {
        templateUrl: 'store.html',
        controller: 'StoreController'
    })
    .when('/groups', {
        templateUrl: 'groups.html',
        controller: 'GroupsController'
    })
    .when('/purchases', {
        templateUrl: 'purchases.html',
        controller: 'PurchaseController'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/store'});
```

The problem is that I have one more link in my HTML file:

```
<a href="logout">Log Out</a>
```

Angular is not allowing me to click this link, because otherwise part of the config is catching it.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried absolute links? E.g.

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="/store">Stores</a></li>
        <li><a href="/groups">Groups</a></li>
        <li><a href="/purchases">Purchases</a></li>
        <li><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And logout also as /logout?

With HTML5 pushstate i think its handy to keep the urls absolute. Let me know how you go with this, i think its as simple as adding a /. What kind of domain are you using?

Comment: I can't add '/' to logut because it is generated for me by Django: <a href="{% url 'enterprises:logout' %}">{% trans 'logout' %}</a>. It is in localhost

Comment: Cant you just add it in front? <a href="/{% url 'enterprises:logout' %}">{% trans 'logout' %}</a>? How did it go on the other href values?

Comment: No I can't. I found one solution. I added target="_self" to the Logout link.